# react-redux Provider cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I fully reinstalled all my application and now I have a problem to build react application. 
[image]

The problem file has the following view:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import createLogger from "redux-logger";
import App from "./components/App.jsx";
import * as reducers from "./reducers";
import types from "./constants/actions";
import message from "./constants/message";
import mid from "./middleWare/mid";

const logger = createLogger();
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    {
        userName: 'N/A',
        error: '',
        info: '',
        services: [],
        carwashes: [],
        backUrl : ''
    },
    applyMiddleware(mid, logger)
);

const destination = document.querySelector("#container");

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    destination
);
```

Do you have any idea what was missed ?

React, redux and react-redux were installed

[image]

Comment: What happens if you  <Provider store={store}> and leave just the <App/> ? Does it compile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks more like an issue with es6. You may be missing some of the babel packages you may have had globally installed. Fully delete the node_modules folder and then do a yarn install.

This is not complaining about the Provider, it's complaining about the < arrow